# setup gzip for svg on apache2 server in ubuntu12.10

Tags: apache2

I need to enable gzip for svg globally but not able going well. I have gone through a lot of links nothing seems to work. to keep in simple below are the steps

after installing apache I placed a folder(mysvgtest) with a Index.html file with default location /var/www
I was able to browse to the location from the browser and the page rendered 
`http://localhost/svgtest/Index.html` 
I ran "a2enmod deflate" and it gave me that the module is loaded.
then I went to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled and opened deflate.conf
over there I added AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
I restarted apache 
the svg file is not getting gziped.
is there any thing else I am missing I do not see any option to change the compression level.

thanks